# Question about quantile function

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with cdf $F$. Then the quantile function of $F$ is defined as

$$F^{-1}(y)=\inf\{x\in\Bbb{R} : F(x)\ge y\}.$$

> *Problem.* Then there is a random varible $Y$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and $F^{-1}(Y)=X$ with probability 1?

If $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing, it is easy to find such $Y$ - just take $Y=F(X)$. Even if $F$ is continuous (there is no certani that $F$ is strictly increasing) then we can find such $Y$. (Proposition 3.1 of [this pdf file](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse.pdf).) However, I don't know how to find such $Y$ if there is no certain that $F$ is continuous. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nondecreasing function $F$ has at most countably many discontinuities, let's say at $x_j$, $j \in J$, corresponding to values that $X$ takes with nonzero probability.  Let $T$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and independent of $X$.  Then take
$Y = T F(X-) + (1-T) F(X)$ 
where $F(X-) = \lim_{x \to X-} F(x)$.