# What does this notation mean? ( $X=\inf\{ x : U \le F(x) \}$ )

Tags: statistics, notation, supremum-and-infimum, sampling

What does ( $X= \inf\{ x : U \le F(x) \}$ ) mean?

I know the concept of inf, found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum)

I found the notation in the title at the end of the chapter on the Inverse Transform Sampling Method where $F(x)$ is the CDF cumulative density function of X and $U$ a random number generate with Uniform distribution $[0,1]$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: @Leon that could help. So the quantile function is the inverse of the CDF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function

Comment: It means "Every random variable $X$ can be considered as a Quantile function of a uniform random variable $U$". This statement ca be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789909/question-about-quantile-function

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Not sure how much you know about probability, but random numbers like $U$ are formally defined as a function from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ to $(\R,\mathcal B(\R)$. You can see more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable).

Here the probability space is $(\R,\mathcal B(\R))$ and $X$ is a random variable from $\R\to\R$, formally $X(\omega)=\inf\{x:U(\omega)\le F(x)\}$ for $\omega\in\R$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. How would you read ( X=inf{x:U≤F(x)} ) with words?

Comment: @ChrisWang I am wondering that it is a statement rather than a definition of a quantity, because $F$ is the cdf of $X$ and $X$ is defined as an infimum!

Comment: Well I suppose its possible there exists a random variable $X$ for which this identity holds.

Answer (score 0):

$U$ is a number and $F$ is a function of one variable. When you put a number $x$ into that function, you get a number $F(x).$ Whether $U\le{}$that number depends of course on what $F(x)$ is, and that depends on what $x$ is. Thus you may put in one number $x$ and find that $U\le F(x)$ and another value of $x$ and find that $U\not\le F(x).$ This distinguishes some values of $x$ from others. Thereby it defines a set of certain values of $x.$ The notation in the question refers to the infimum, i.e. the greatest lower bound, of that set.

For example, suppose $F(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$ for $x\ge0$ and $U= 0.75.$ Then
\begin{align}
& \{x : U \le F(x)\} = \{x : x\ge \ln 4\} = [\ln4,+\infty)
\end{align}
and that set has an infimum.